# Plot multiple columns of pandas DataFrame using Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, seaborn

suppose I have DataFrame with columns `['X_Axis','col_2','col_3',...,'col_n',]`

I need to plot the first column on X-Axis and rest on Y-Axis.
FYI : all the values have been grouped according to X-Axis, the X-Axis values range from `0-25` and all other column values have been normalized to the scale of `0 - 1`. I want it on same graph plot, not subplots.

Preferred : FactorPlot , normal line graph.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

- Some seaborn plots will accept a wide dataframe, `sns.pointplot(data=df, x='X_Axis', y='col_2')`, but not `sns.pointplot(data=df, x='X_Axis', y=['col_2', 'col_3'])`, so it's better to reshape the DataFrame.
- Reshape the DataFrame from wide to long with [`pandas.DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html).

  - Converting the dataframe from a wide to long form is standard for [all seaborn plots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/api.html), not just the examples shown.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### Sample DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'X_Axis':[1,3,5,7,10,20],
                   'col_2':[.4,.5,.4,.5,.5,.4],
                   'col_3':[.7,.8,.9,.4,.2,.3],
                   'col_4':[.1,.3,.5,.7,.1,.0],
                   'col_5':[.5,.3,.6,.9,.2,.4]})

# display(df)
   X_Axis  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5
0       1    0.4    0.7    0.1    0.5
1       3    0.5    0.8    0.3    0.3
2       5    0.4    0.9    0.5    0.6
3       7    0.5    0.4    0.7    0.9
4      10    0.5    0.2    0.1    0.2
5      20    0.4    0.3    0.0    0.4

# convert to long (tidy) form
dfm = df.melt('X_Axis', var_name='cols', value_name='vals')

# display(dfm.head())
   X_Axis   cols  vals
0       1  col_2   0.4
1       3  col_2   0.5
2       5  col_2   0.4
3       7  col_2   0.5
4      10  col_2   0.5
```

### Current Plot Methods

#### `catplot`: figure-level

Use [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) with `kind=` (e.g. `kind='point'` to reproduce the `FactorPlot` default):

```py
g = sns.catplot(x="X_Axis", y="vals", hue='cols', data=dfm, kind='point')
```

[image]

#### [`pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html): axes-level

```py
sns.pointplot(x="X_Axis", y="vals", hue='cols', data=dfm)
```

[image]

### Original

#### `factorplot`: was renamed to `catplot` v0.9.0 (July 2018)

New versions of seaborn get warning:

> The `factorplot` function has been renamed to `catplot`. The original name will be removed in a future release. Please update your code. Note that the default `kind` in `factorplot` (`'point'`) has changed `'strip'` in `catplot`.

```py
g = sns.factorplot(x="X_Axis", y="vals", hue='cols', data=dfm)

# using pd.melt instead of pd.DataFrame.melt for pandas < 0.20.0
# dfm = pd.melt(df, 'X_Axis', var_name='cols',  value_name='vals')
# g = sns.factorplot(x="X_Axis", y="vals", hue='cols', data=dfm)
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 10):

in addition to mighty @jezrael for those who come from google if you intend to plot lines with the index of the original dataframe just do as follows:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_2':[.4,.5,.4,.5,.5,.4],
                   'col_3':[.7,.8,.9,.4,.2,.3],
                   'col_4':[.1,.3,.5,.7,.1,.0],
                   'col_5':[.5,.3,.6,.9,.2,.4]})

# resetting index before melting to save the current index in 'index' column...
df = df.reset_index().melt('index', var_name='cols',  value_name='vals')
g = sns.catplot(x="index", y="vals", hue='cols', data=df, kind='point')
```